# How can I specify multiple selector jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my html code:

```
<input type="text" id="home">
<input type"text" id="dog">
```

I need to do something to read the values in these fields. So I wrote my jquery code:

```
//this code is wrong because it doesn't work
$('input[type="text"][id="home"] input[type="text"][id="dog"]')....
```

How I can select something like this?  Can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For selecting multiple items use comma in between them

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#home, #dog').val("hello");
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>

 <input type="text" id="home">
<input type"text" id="dog">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a comma between two selectors when you are selecting based on multiple criteria.  A simple example is:

```
$("#element1, #element2, #element3")
```

Your example:

```
$('input[type="text"][id="home"], input[type="text"][id="dog"]')
```

See [Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

you should use `$('#home, #dog');`